# How to execute stored procedure and get output from the stored procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have been trying to insert a record with using EF6 by way of calling a stored procedure and trying to get the output from the stored procedure which is the newly created ID but keep running into brick walls.

I have a stored procedure that has an OUTPUT of ContactID

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertContact]
    @ContactID int output,
    @Name nvarchar(50)
AS
insert into [Contact]
    (Name) values (@Name)
    set @ContactID = @@IDENTITY
```

I am calling the stored procedure and passing the values like this...

```
return Convert.ToInt32(AWJE.Database.SqlQuery<int>
   ("usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name));
```

That didn't work either I got the following error...(and I had posted this earlier and answered it myself, and it didn't work).

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible Error

Then I went and tried this...

```
return AWJE.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
    ("exec usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name);
```

When this gets called I get the following error...

> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@Name".

As you can see the variable @Name is in the stored procedure and that I am passing the variable @Name.

So then I tried this

```
return AWJE.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
   ("exec usp_InsertContact @ContactID OUTPUT, @Name", contact.Name);
```

And that gives this error...

> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@ContactID".

So I am kind of lost with how to do this, I know how to do this strictly using ADO.NET.
I have looked around for an answer for this but not understanding examples I have seen because the examples I have seen are being mixed with SqlParameter.Add etc...

Comment: `this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving you deep description of how to do it in step by step. T

here are basically two ways to do this on directly with EF the other one with just pure SQL.

In EF you have to add your sproc as function here is an article on how to do it  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

or pure sql way like so,

```
SqlParameter p1= new SqlParameter("@p1", "Test");
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@p2", "Test2");

//Executing the stored procedure from your database context
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_StoredProc @p1, @p2", p1, p2);
```

Comment: With the pure sql statement you have, isn't this the same thing?
AWJE.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name)?. I had asked a question similar to your statement that had to do with making that more cleaner and elegant and what I showed was the other way, which was more of a cleaner way to do it

Comment: Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@ContactID". Is the reason why you are getting the error it not the point of a cleaner way it the point of letting the EF treat your variable as SqlParameter. Even the above answer still uses SQL parameters you may write it in one line but doing something like this  ("exec usp_InsertContact @Name", contact.Name);   might not even run to compilation.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
using (ConEntities context = new ConEntities())
    {
    // ContactID is an output parameter.
    ObjectParameter ContactID = new ObjectParameter("ContactID", typeof(int));
    SqlParameter Name = new SqlParameter("@Name", "hello sir");
    context.usp_InsertContact(ContactID, Name);
    //Console.WriteLine(ContactID.Value); 
    }
```

we can like this also

```
var parameters = new[] { 
        new SqlParameter("@0", SqlDbType.Int32) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }, 
        new SqlParameter("@1", "MY Name")
    };

    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("exec usp_InsertContact @ContactID =@0 output, @Name =@1", parameters);

    int d = (int)parameters[0].Value;
```

Comment: Throws an error at context.usp_InsertContact(ContactID, Name);, the error is "cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to 'string'"

Comment: The @ContactID ==  @@IDENTITY isn't the issue, the ContactID is an identity column and increments the ID :)

Comment: yes i got it by mistake i put then i deleted :) is second solution also not working

Comment: @Chris solution output parameter is not correct i have update `ContactID`

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this

```
   var outputId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "outputId", Value = 0, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };

    Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        @"spProcedureName @p1, @outputId out",
        new SqlParameter("p1", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name),
        outputId
    );

   return Convert.ToInt32(outputId.Value);
```